# Check user Login using Repository pattern c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository, 3-tier

I'm new at design patterns and I'm trying to make some example using repository pattern (Maybe I'll ask some stupid question using stupid example and if it's so please tell me).

I have this repository in my BusinessLogicLayer:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    LogIn GetByUsernameAndPassword(LogIn user);
}
```

and in my data access layer

```
class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    ChatAppDBContext _db = new ChatAppDBContext();
    public LogIn GetByUsernameAndPassword(LogIn login)
    {
        return _db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == login.Email & u.Password == login.UserPassword).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

but it throws an error that Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'DataAccessLayer.User' to
>   'BusinessLogicLayer.Model.LogIn'

How can I solve that?

Comment: try putting `Select(u => new LogIn { Email = u.Email, UserPassword = u.Password })` before `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Better yet: `return _db.Users.Any(u => u.Email == login.Email & u.Password == login.UserPassword) ? login : null;`

Comment: But we agree that you should never ever EVER store passwords in plain text, right? For more information see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html and http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html and http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html

Comment: @Corak yeah I know it's just for practice about repository and 3 tier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    ChatAppDBContext _db = new ChatAppDBContext();
    public Login GetByUsernameAndPassword(LogIn login)
    {
         var userResult = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == login.Email & u.Password == login.UserPassword);

         if (userResult == null)
             // throw new Exception() or return new Login();

         Login loginResult = new Login();
         loginResult.Email = userResult.Email;
         return loginResult;                    
    }
}
```

Comment: I can return User(table in my db) there but I can't access User from my interface which is in another class library

Comment: I have updated my code. You can get each of the results in userResult object and set to a new instance of loginResult and return loginResult.

Comment: Note that the `FirstOrDefault()` method can return `default(T)`: `null` for a reference type. So, the appropriate checking of the return value should be introduced.

Answer (score 1):

@Oluwafemi is correct. You just need to create a user "view model" to return.

```
class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
       ChatAppDBContext _db = new ChatAppDBContext();
       public UserModel GetByUsernameAndPassword(LogIn login)
       {
           return _db.Users
             .Where(u => u.Email == login.Email & u.Password == login.UserPassword)
             .FirstOrDefault()
             .Select(x => new UserModel
             {
                  Name = x.Name
             });
       }
}

public class UserModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```